# MySQL query return different results every time

Tags: mysql

I have the query

```
 SELECT g.f_id as f_code
     , ss.f_name as f_storage
     , g.f_name as f_goods
     , g.f_scancode
     , s.f_price
     , SUM(s.f_qty*s.f_type) as f_qty
     , SUM(s.f_qty*s.f_type)*g.f_saleprice as f_totalsale
  FROM a_store s 
  JOIN c_goods g 
    ON g.f_id = s.f_goods 
  JOIN c_storages ss 
    ON ss.f_id = s.f_store 
  JOIN a_header h 
    ON h.f_id = s.f_document  
 WHERE h.f_date <= '2020-06-22'  
   AND h.f_state = 1
 GROUP 
    BY g.f_id
     , ss.f_name
     , g.f_name
     , g.f_scancode
     , s.f_price
HAVING SUM(s.f_qty*s.f_type) <> 0
 ORDER 
    BY SUM(s.f_qty*s.f_type) asc
```

Every time this query returns different result and different rows count without the changes in the database.  I cant understand, why.

Comment: All the non aggregated columns that appear in the `select` list but not in the `group by list` may return arbitrary values.

Comment: You have to decide which f_saleprice you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

I was change the version of mysql from 5.7 to 8.0 and problem was gone. Why it worked wrong on version 5.7 remains a mystery.